# hide active and show one using jquery css

Tags: jquery, html, hidden

I'm trying to create an auto hide option that allows users to click on links to reveal/display items, but I want to be able to automatically close active displays when the users choose a different subject.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    $("#myp-0", ).click(function(){
        $("#loose-0").toggle(600);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    $("#myp-1", ).click(function(){
        $("#loose-1").toggle(600);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    $("#myp-2", ).click(function(){
        $("#loose-2").toggle(600);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="myp-0">click</p>
<p id="loose-0"> I will disappear.</p>
<p id="myp-1">click</p>
<p id="loose-1"> I will disappear.</p>
<p id="myp-2">click</p>
<p id="loose-2">I will disappear.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So, the example shows links that displays the content. How do I hide the content until a link is clicked and when I tap a link, show the content, but make the jquery check to see if any other links are active and close them automatically?

Comment: preferably shorten the code too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wild card with hide method and next to toggle.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('p[id*="myp"]').click(function() {
        $('p[id*="loose"]').hide();
        $(this).next('p').toggle(600);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="myp-0">click</p>
  <p id="loose-0">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
  <p id="myp-1">click</p>
  <p id="loose-1">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
  <p id="myp-2">click</p>
  <p id="loose-2">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are comparing  the id and filtering it with match wont it be slower then using the exact id as selector?i may be wrong. just asking for clarity

Comment: Yap but op html didn't use any class and i don't want to add extra class in his markup .

Comment: This is exactly what classes are for. Saying you don't want to add classes to the markup is like saying 'I don't want to fix the issue properly'. With this method the OP has to ensure that they apply a new unique id every time they add a set of `p` elements. Also note that clicking the same element multiple times repeatedly hides/slides it down.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right here but when the page is complex with some master page and some other partial pages with external classes and things get more mushy with classes  hey i like classes but using id is more intact i believe .

Comment: @RAHULSR It's not an either/or situation. Classes have one use and Ids have another. Classes are used to *group* elements/behaviours - which is why they should be used here. Ids are used to uniquely identify elements when you specifically want to target a single instance, ie. not what 's being done here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you might be right but in this case all 3 of our answers work the wild card search , the class selecttor and the id selector i am just saying id selector is the fastest one

Comment: It may be faster in processing terms, but 50ms is a completely pointless saving if the code is more brittle and takes longer to write and maintain.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly note that you only need a single document.ready event handler per page.

To simplify the code you can use the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle. To achieve this place common classes on all the clickable `p` elements and those which are toggled. You can then use DOM traversal, `next()` in this case, to find the related element and toggle it. You can then select all other elements unrelated to the event, and hide them. Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myp').click(function() {
    var $target = $(this).next('.loose').toggle(600);
    $('.loose').not($target).slideUp(600);
  });
});
```

```css
p { margin: 0; }
.loose { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="myp">click</p>
<p class="loose">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="myp">click</p>
<p class="loose">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="myp">click</p>
<p class="loose">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work but may need some changes try this

```
  .hidden{
    display :none;
   }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#myp-0,#myp-1,#myp-2").click(function(){
        $('.newCLass').addClass('hidden')
         $(this).next('p').toggleClass('hidden')
        });
    }); 
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="myp-0">click</p>
    <p id="loose-0" class="newCLass">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p id="myp-1">click</p>
    <p id="loose-1" class="newCLass">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p id="myp-2">click</p>
    <p id="loose-2" class="newCLass">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use hide() funcion, and merge all in one function on document ready:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#loose-0").hide();
    $("#loose-1").hide();
    $("#loose-2").hide();
   
    $("#myp-0", ).click(function(){
        $("#loose-0").toggle(600);
    });

    $("#myp-1", ).click(function(){
        $("#loose-1").toggle(600);
    });

    $("#myp-2", ).click(function(){
        $("#loose-2").toggle(600);
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="myp-0">click</p>
<p id="loose-0">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p id="myp-1">click</p>
<p id="loose-1">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p id="myp-2">click</p>
<p id="loose-2">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>

</body>
</html>
```